# I use tensorflow2 to identify captcha image,but happend some wrong

Tags: tensorflow2.0

this is  my code :

```
number = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
absPath='F:/Projects/AI/Tensorflow/verificationcode/image/'
imagePaths=os.listdir('./image')


model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPool2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPool2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPool2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPool2D((2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dropout(0.25),
    Dense(40,activation='softmax')
])
model(inputs=tf.keras.Input(shape=(80,170,3)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32,shuffle=True, epochs=5, validation_freq=1)
```

this is  my  model:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 78, 168, 32)       896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 76, 166, 32)       9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 38, 83, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 36, 81, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 79, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 39, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 37, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 13, 35, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 17, 128)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 15, 256)        295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 13, 256)        590080    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 1, 6, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1536)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1536)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 40)                61480     
=================================================================
Total params: 1,233,736
Trainable params: 1,233,736
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I use  3935 samples to train,it is result:

3616/3935 [==========================>...] - ETA: 10s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0105
3648/3935 [==========================>...] - ETA: 9s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0112
3680/3935 [===========================>..] - ETA: 8s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0128
3712/3935 [===========================>..] - ETA: 7s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0129
3744/3935 [===========================>..] - ETA: 6s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0134
3776/3935 [===========================>..] - ETA: 5s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0143
3808/3935 [============================>.] - ETA: 4s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0142
3840/3935 [============================>.] - ETA: 3s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0148
3872/3935 [============================>.] - ETA: 2s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0155
3904/3935 [============================>.] - ETA: 1s - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0166
3935/3935 [==============================] - 135s 34ms/sample - loss: 14.7558 - accuracy: 0.0170

this is a captcha image:
[captcha image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gTW6.png)

the loss unchanged, the accuracy is very low

How to solve it ?? thanks!